# What is the difference between 'Physics' and 'Physics Meta'?

Tags: support, meta

I recently joined Stack Exchange. So I am not used to this system (also I'm a foreigner; Korean). I joined this group because I want to get physics information. But there are two choices: Physics and Physics meta. Which should I choose?

(I'm sorry about my English writing skill; I'm practicing now.)

Comment: We're all foreigners here - none of us were born in the internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should choose the main [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) site for your actual physics questions. This Physics Meta site is for questions about the operation and policies of the main Physics site.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: Note that this question, about how to use the site, is correctly posted on Physics Meta. :-)